# What is the best way to export a content type and its fields?

Tags: 8, configuration

How can we export a content type, including its fields, and import it into staging or production?

Comment: I would suggest looking into [features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features)

Comment: Depends a bit on the context. Normally you do that simply via config. If you don't use [configuration management](https://www.drupal.org/docs/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration) yet, you should first have a look at that. And for more advanced needs like syncing isolated features like a content type or a paragraph type with all its fields and settings across multiple multi-site instances (not across environments) you use Features as @ArmandoSilva said.

Comment: I started a bounty on the duplicate as this question gets asked quite often in different forms and it would be nice to have a more detailed/up to date answer

Comment: We have config sync setup but there doesn't seem to be a way to export/import just a single content type.